# PHP str_replace not working with query

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm having this:

```
$a = "t4.length = "50" AND t4.type = "F" AND (t3.minutes*60*1000+t3.seconds*1000+t3.milliseconds) < 22000";
```

I want to replace this string with other string, I tried str_replace but this function doesn't replace this string.
I'm trying this.

```
$c = str_replace($a , '', $b);
```

Comment: `str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )`. This is the function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I know this function. I already checked it but not working that's why I posted here. Please try it with yourself then let me know it is working or not. Don't down vote without check.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was my fault, there were other extra spaces that's why this function was not working. I truncated all extra spaces then it was working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong code

```
 $c = str_replace($b , '', $a);
```

$b is key to find and replace

'' is replacement

$a is subject to replace

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php